# Calculating if an object is blocked from sight by another object

Tags: geometry, triangulation

Is there an equation to determine if an object at altitude A can be seen at altitude B if there is an object between them at altitude C?

Something to do with triangles I think... I know it has something to do with right angled triangles... Heres the problem I have a tower at point A and a technician at point B who needs to be in sight of the tower. I drew a diagram that showed to me that a peak between the two points could be seen over from closer up but would block the view from further away.

I know the distance between the technician and the tower and the distance between the peak and both other objects.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a diagram from a side on perspective?

Comment: I know it has something to do with right angled triangles... Heres the problem I have a tower at point A and a technician at point B who needs to be in sight of the tower. I drew a diagram that showed to me that a peak between the two points could be seen over from closer up but would block the view from further away.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you have described, there is no general formula for what you are asking though. Can you work out the precise distance at which the technician begins to have his view obstructed?

Comment: I know the distance between the technician and the tower and the distance between the peak and both other objects.

Comment: By peak do you mean the top of the tower? Does the technician have to see the entire tower? Are A,B,C variables or constants?

Comment: Sorry, by peak I mean a hill between the technician and her tower, and the technician only needs to see the antenna on the top of the tower. The tower and peak are at constant heights but the technician is rambling over uneven terrain

Comment: I would draw a right angled triangle, with the hypotenuse going from the top of the antenna to the technicians eyes, the base of the triangle going from the eyes to the same altitude on the tower. Now you can see if the peak of the hill hits the hypotenuse then the vision will be obstructed. Now im assuming you want to find how far back the tech has to stand for a hill whose peak is a fixed height. So look at the case where the hill just touches the hypotenuse draw a line from the hills peak on the hypotenuse to the base of the triangle and you will have a smaller traingle within your larger

Comment: One. You can then work out the distance between the hill and the tech using pythag or trig and the numbers you have. Then if the tech stands further away than this he will he able to see the tower.

Comment: Thanks I found the trig. To calculate the height at any point I used the calculated obtuse angle of the right angled triangle (created by the difference in height between the technician and the tower antenna) converted into radians and multipled by the distance of the peak from the obtuse angle. Then I compared this result against the actual height of the peak. If the peak is higher then the tower is not visible.

Comment: On the actual Earth, if the technician stands too far back then due to the curvature of the geoid, the view of the antenna will certainly be blocked by the hill (which may itself be under the horizon, that is, blocked from view by other terrain). You could instead assume a flat Earth, but I would say it explicitly if that is so.

Comment: @gridironman One sketch is better than many descriptions, so better to upload a sketch regarding heights and distances.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeking is the intersection of a segment $AB$ with a triangle $C$ in 3D:

---

[image: SegTriInt]

---

Searching for that will lead to many discussions of the problem, by e.g.,
[DanSunday](http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html).